# Link to "FreeBSD’s How to Answer" on "How To Answer" page is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks

The link to "FreeBSD’s How to Answer" in the Related section on [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) page of Stackoverflow is broken:

[image: a]

[FreeBSD’s How to Answer](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/articles/freebsd-questions/x218.html) -> Result is "Page not found".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done. It should be there in the next deploy.